# SQL Join problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a problem trying to join two tables

TableA

```
+----------+--------------+
| PersonID | customerId   |
+----------+--------------+
|      123 |          456 |
|      258 |          145 |
|      789 |          469 |
+----------+--------------+
```

TableB

```
+-----------+------------+
| PersonID  | CustomerId |
+-----------+------------+
|       123 | **456**    |
|       123 | 789        |
|       123 | 256        |
|       258 | 145        |
|       258 | 999        |
+-----------+------------+
```

I want to create a table joining by tableA and tableB like this

```
+----------+------------------------------------------+
| PersonId |                CustomerId                |
+----------+------------------------------------------+
|      123 | 456 (First customerid value from TableB) |
|      258 | 145 (First customerid value from TableB) |
+----------+------------------------------------------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? And what determines which record is "first" in table B? To be certain that you're getting the desired result, you will need to specify a column by which table B should be sorted.

Comment: We have using sql management studio 2012. First record can be determined sorting customerid desc

Comment: `First record can be determined sorting customerid desc` That isn't what your sample output shows.... Also it appears as if you have the exact data you need in TableA, so why even bother with the join?

Answer (score 1):

This code will work. But you really need something to sort on in `TableB` to tell it which `CustomerId` you want.  Because I'm only sorting by `PersonId` for the ROW_NUMBER you could get erratic results if the index used changes.  This will give you an idea of how to get it done though.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (PersonId int, CustomerId int);

INSERT INTO TableA VALUES 
                (123, 456),
                (258, 145),
                (789, 469);

CREATE TABLE TableB (PersonId int, CustomerId int);

INSERT INTO TableB VALUES
            (123, 456),
            (123, 789),
            (123, 256),
            (258, 145),
            (258, 999);

WITH MyCte AS (SELECT TableB.*, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY PersonId) AS RowNum
            FROM TableB)
SELECT TableA.PersonId, MyCte.CustomerId
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN MyCte
    ON TableA.PersonId = MyCte.PersonId
WHERE MyCte.RowNum = 1;
```

What you really want is something like this where there is a `CreateDate` (or something similar) in `TableB`

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (PersonId int, CustomerId int);

INSERT INTO TableA VALUES 
                (123, 456),
                (258, 145),
                (789, 469);

CREATE TABLE TableB (PersonId int, CustomerId int, EntryDate datetime);

INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (123, 456, getdate()); WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (123, 789, getdate()); WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (123, 256, getdate()); WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (258, 145, getdate()); WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (258, 999, getdate()); WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

WITH MyCte AS (SELECT TableB.*, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY EntryDate) AS RowNum
            FROM TableB)
SELECT TableA.PersonId, MyCte.CustomerId
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN MyCte
    ON TableA.PersonId = MyCte.PersonId
WHERE MyCte.RowNum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

My method is using the "not exists" clause to check for any records. What my method will do is faster than most methods to resolve this issue. You can also select any values from TableB. The "not exists" clause is saying 'find the customerId where there is not a greater customerId.'

```
    SELECT A.PersonID, B.customerId
    FROM TableA as A
    JOIN TableB as B ON B.PersonID = A.PersonID
    WHERE not exists 
                     (SELECT 1 
                      FROM TableB AS eB 
                      WHERE eB.PersonID = B.PersonID 
                      AND eB.CustomerId > B.CustomerId)
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something that's basically a MAX.  If you look at the requested results they want the first entry in the table .. not the highest.

Comment: I was going off this comment by the user: First record can be determined sorting customerid desc

Comment: You're welcome. Did that solve your problem?